# How can present view controller from specific view controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm starting a navigation flow. I'm starting from AViewController and I'm navigating in app. AViewController -> BViewController -> CViewController -> DViewController. While in DViewController, I want to push EViewController. But I want AViewController to do this push, not DViewController. So I want my presentingViewController to be AViewController. With this, other ViewControllers(BViewController, CViewController, DViewController) have to be dismissed. In the last case, my navigation flow should be like this: AViewController -> EViewController. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: That’s a good candidate for the [Coordinator Pattern](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/71/how-to-use-the-coordinator-pattern-in-ios-apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the navigation stack of a view controller, use [`setViewControllers(_, animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621861-setviewcontrollers). If you pass in your existing `AViewController` and a new `EViewController` then your final navigation stack will be just those two.

There is no need to manually rebuild the stack you want by pushing and popping individual controllers.

Answer (score 0):

do you want eviewcontroller back to Aviewcontroller, or you can push Aviewcontroller to Eviewcontroller

```
 func pushFrom(vc: UIViewController.Type) {
    guard let nv = self.navigationController else {
      return
   }
  for controller in nv.viewControllers as Array {
    if controller.isKind(of: vc.self) {
let eviewcontroller = Eviewcontroller()
     controller.navigationController!.pushViewController(eviewcontroller, 
 animated: true)
        break
     }
  }
}
```

Then

```
 pushFrom(vc: AViewcontroller.self)
```

Comment: Didn't back to AViewController when I call navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Comment: @EmircanAydın you can try: navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pop all the view controller till `AViewcontroller` as

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Then

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(EViewcontroller, animated: true)
```

Now it is AViewcontroller -> EViewcontroller

**Another solution**

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(EViewcontroller, animated: true)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
        self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: 1) // Remove B
        self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: 2) // Remove C
        self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: 3) // Remove D
}
```

**OR**
Add this in EViewcontroller's `viewDidAppear`

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: 1) // Remove B
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: 2) // Remove C
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: 3) // Remove D
```

Comment: First, the AViewController appears on the screen. This should not happen.

Comment: Updated. Check my another solution.

Answer (score 0):

First , create a function that helps you to push `A to F` in `Viewcontroller` A

```
  func aToF(){
    let fVC= self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your vc Id") as! FViewController
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(fVC, animated: false)
}
```

And where you go back to `root and push F` call this :

```
  let turnBack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] as! AViewController
  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
  turnBack.aToF()
```

> I do not recommend creating a new instance from an already memorized viewcontroller, but this is one of the easiest ways.